NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID in self signed certificate for local development on xampp
I've followed multiple tutorials, so many that I don't even know where I am anymore but I just can't get anything to work.
I work locally using xampp and use hosts file editor so that when I access the real domain on my development computer, it loads the dev copy instead. But now everything wants to be ssl, this is causing problems. In firefox (well palemoon) I could just add an exception to my self signed certificates but I need to be able to test in chrome without telling it to proceed on every page load.
The first thing I tried was creating a ca certificate
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt

and then generating and signing the certificates
openssl req -new -nodes -sha256 -out sub.mydomain.com.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout sub.mydomain.com.key
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in sub.mydomain.com.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out sub.mydomain.com.crt

I then installed the ca.crt into my trusted authorities in both chrome and windows. And I installed the sub.mydomain.com.crt into windows too just for good measure.
The error I get with that is :
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: sub.mydomain.com

Issuer: localhost

Expires on: May 14, 2025

Current date: May 15, 2024

But I am accessing sub.mydomain.com, I've triple checked .
Then I tried
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout sub.mydomain.com.key -out sub.mydomain.com.crt -days 365 -subj "/CN=sub.mydomain.com"

That gives me :
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: sub.mydomain.com

Issuer: sub.mydomain.com

Then I tried the makecert.bat file that comes in xampp, I changed it to change the filenames, because I have multiple subdomains that all need their own ssl certificates so server.key and server.crt would not do! Again, installed in windows and chrome, cleared the cache, restarted the browser and again got NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
I also tried the SAN changes to my openssl.conf from this thread
Creating self signed certificate for domain and subdomains - NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
